# Logic App - HTTP Action - Loop until 200

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app with an http action. 
As the reply policy allows at most 4 retries I put the activity inside a do-until loop (with max count and timeout) using the http status code as escape variable (until it is 200).

This image should make this more clear
[image]

At runtime I get this error

> [EDIT]**InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'HTTPAction'**[EDIT]: Unable to process template language expressions for action 'HttpAction' [..] The template language expression 'equals(outputs('HttpAction')['statusCode'], 200)' cannot be evaluated because property 'statusCode' cannot be selected.

Any hints?

Thanks, Alessandro

[EDIT]The http request just works (tried with fiddler), in the workflow i suppose it just doesn't get executed due to the template error (why does it fail at runtime and not in edit mode?)[EDIT]

Comment: It is possible your HttpActions fails without generating outputs. Can you try syntax equals(outputs('HttpAction')?['statusCode'], 200).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. As I edited the error refers to an invalid template. In addition if I make the same request using fiddler I get my 200.

Comment: What happens if you use actions('HttpAction').['statusCode'] instead of outputs ?

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Consider I created "equals(outputs('HttpAction')['statusCode'], 200)" using the basic mode using the web gui and would like not to require coding skills (for other users). Moreover that expression won't be converted to basic mode editing, making the workflow condition less readable

Comment: @equals(actions('HttpAction').['statusCode'], 200) gives error on saving "Expected token 'Identifier'"
I used @equals(actions('CallClarifaiTags').statusCode, 200) and then got 
"Unable to process template language expressions for action 'HttpAction': 'The template language expression 'equals(actions('HttpAction').statusCode, 200)' cannot be evaluated because property 'statusCode' doesn't exist"

Comment: You actually want @equals(actions('HttpAction')['statusCode'], 200), or, using the dot syntax @equals(actions('HttpAction').statusCode, 200)

Answer (score 0):

Going to reply for readable code. 
I just made a quick POC to simulate your scenario, but I can't reproduce your issue.

Code of my Do-Until:

```
"Until": {
            "actions": {
                "HttpGetMyValues": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "headers": {
                            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "@parameters('OcpApimSubscriptionKey')"
                        },
                        "method": "GET",
                        "uri": "https://myendpointuri"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "Http"
                }
            },
            "expression": "@equals(outputs('HttpGetMyValues')['statusCode'], 200)",
            "limit": {
                "count": 1,
                "timeout": "PT1M"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "Until"
        }
```

I can save and run the Logic App without problems.

Comment: You used outputs not actions

Comment: Yes, so did you in your first example. I think I used the same method to design the poc using the designer only. Designer uses outputs, which is working just fine in my case.

Comment: As i said, I can't reproduce it, not during design and not during runtime. Can you remove the  DoUntil & execute the HttpAction normally? Just to verify what response you are getting. Output of this test might explain why the dountil is failing.

Comment: The only difference I see is the method (in my case it is a post with a body)

Comment: The action outside the loop responds 200/4xx/5xx. Depending on the load the endpoint rejects me with casual 4xx/5xx then after some retries it gives me 200. This is the reason why I wanted to use a loop based on the response statusCode.

Answer (score 0):

Retry policy is configurable, currently only available via code view, but we plan to enable it in designer very soon. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#retry-policies) the documentation.

```
"retryPolicy" : {
      "type": "<type-of-retry-policy>",
      "interval": <retry-interval>,
      "count": <number-of-retry-attempts>
    }
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that max retrypolicy count is 4

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the game, but the error is due to the condition that ends the 'do-until' loop being contained within the loop itself.  You'll need to use a value that is outside of the loop as reference.  I suggest:

1. Creating a variable before the 'do-until' action with the default value as '400'
2. Using the variable as the value the 'Status code' value needs to equal
3. Updating (set-variable in Logic Apps) the variable at the end of each loop iteration to equal the 'Status code'.

Answer (score 0):

In the Until control:

1. Click Edit Advanced Mode
2. Replace the text with `@equals(actions('HTTPAction').status, 'Succeeded')`
3. The code means stop do until loop when the HTTPAction has completed